# NullPointerException at Radio Group on dialogbox

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, radio-group

I have two `radiogroup` on `FormVisitMapping.java`, i put one of them on dialogbox which is trigger by button `onClick()`. but i get an error nullpointerexception only on my radiogroup where in dialog. even i have a similiar code on both of them. i have no idea why this happenned. i've read a question with similiar issue, but nothing solve my problem. here is my code :

```
    btninvoice= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btninvoice);
    btninvoice.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
              final Dialog dialog3 = new Dialog(FormVisitMapping.this);
              dialog3.setContentView(R.layout.penagihan);
              dialog3.setTitle("Isi Data Penagihan:");
              dialog3.show();
              //other stuff
              RadioGroup tes=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.penagihan);
              switch (tes.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
              case R.id.rbtandaterima:
                systemofpayment = "Tanda Terima";
                break;
              case R.id.rbtagihlangsung:
                systemofpayment="Tagih Langsung";
                break;
              default:
                break;
                }
            }
    });
```

i've got NullPointerException on this line :

```
switch (tes.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
```

every help will be apriciated.thank you

Comment: Where do you have this code? Can you put some more context around it?

Comment: i've edited the code with some context around them @Szymon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using `findViewById()` on a wrong view. You haven't included your XML but I'm guessing that you want to find it in dialog's layout.

Change

```
RadioGroup tes=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.penagihan);
```

to

```
RadioGroup tes=(RadioGroup) dialog3.findViewById(R.id.penagihan);
```